# Unified Write Filter Causes Kernel Mode Exception When Enabled on Iot Core Version 10.0.17763.107

Tags: raspberry-pi3, iot, windows-10-iot-core

After installing the unified write filter packages on Iot Core version 10.0.17763.107 which is running on a Raspberyy Pi 3 version B, an unhanded kernel mode exception (blue screen) occurs after the UWF is enabled.

The UWF packages were installed from the Windows10_IoTCore_Packages_ARM32_en-us_17763Oct.iso from the semi-annual servicing channel download link.
The following steps were derived from the article "Using the Unified Write Filter (UWF) on Windows 10 IoT Core."

This process worked on Iot Core version 10.0.17134, however, the UWF package file names are different for the 17763 packages.
After installing the Windows_10_IoT_Core_ARM_Packages.msi from the iso, the packages:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\MSPackages\retail\arm\fre\Microsoft-IoTUAP-UnifiedWriteFilter-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~arm~~.cab

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\MSPackages\retail\arm\fre\ Microsoft-IoTUAP-UnifiedWriteFilter-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~arm~en-us~.cab

were copied to the device into the folder u:\UnifiedWriteFilter

The following commands were ran from a remote powershell session:

- u:
- cd UnifiedWriteFilter
- applyupdate –stage Microsoft-IoTUAP-UnifiedWriteFilter-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~arm~~.cab
- applyupdate –stage Microsoft-IoTUAP-UnifiedWriteFilter-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~arm~en-us~.cab
- applyupdate –commit

The device then appears to install the packages successfully.
Upon restart, the following commands were ran from a remote SSH session:

- uwfmgr.exe volume protect c:
- uwfmgr.exe volume protect u:
- uwfmgr.exe filter enable
- shutdown -r -t 0

When the device restarts, the "Your PC ran into a problem and needs to restart. We''l restart for you" screen appears with:

Stop code: KMODE exception not handled.

What failed: vwififlt.sys

This process has been repeated using two different SD cards.

Is there something that I am doing incorrectly to install and enable UWF for version 17763?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested with the commands in your post. I can reproduce this issue. It seems that you can not protect the data volume(U:) via command `'uwfmgr.exe volume protect u:'`. But it can be protected using the GUID for the volume.

1. Use putty or other tool to connect with the device through SSH, and then redirect to the root of partition `C:`;
2. Get the volume information via command `dir /AL`,you will get the GUID for the data volume:
   [image]
3. Run the command to protect the volume with GUID which got from last step:

   `uwfmgr.exe volume protect \\?\Volume {GUID}`